# Smaller Border on Sizeable Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, border, formborderstyle

I want the Border-Thickness around the Form smaller.

I make `FormBorderStyle = Sizeable`, because I want that Aero Snap works.

Then I found a hint that I need `WM_NCCALCSIZE` for this.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
            break;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

But then I don't have any border.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do that by setting these:

```
ControlBox = false;
MinimizeBox = false;
MaximizeBox = false; 
Text = "";
```

This will be the result:

[image]

Comment: was the answer useful or not?